# loader.load crashing

Tags: three.js

I cannot get loader.load to work!
I am calling it like this:

```
// loader
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(),

callbackModel   = function( geometry ) { 
  createScene( geometry,  90, FLOOR, -50, 105 ) 
}

loader.load(  'oakley/step3.js', callbackModel  );
```

I either get

```
Object # < Object > does not have a definition for 'split', (uncaught TypeError)
```

and more recently, after changing to firefox I get

```
TypeError: zmesh is undefined.
step3.js:1 is malformed (haven't touched it)
```

and

```
TypeError: a is undefined in three.min.js:347
```

and

```
TypeError: ma is undefined in three.min.js:429.
```

I have been following tutorials. Multiple ones in fact. None the less, I cannot get it to work..

Comment: This is likely related to the step3.js file in question, you could try different files that you are sure should be working in three.js. or provide a link to the file. Also it helps debugging to use three.js instead of three.min.js - variable names are obscured in the minified version, making the error messages not so helpful (you could probably have something more informational instead of the undefined "a" and "ma").

Comment: I got an answer on the irc channel, and the for the sake of archiving / helping someone out, here's the answer. The load method I was trying to call is an old version. The new one takes a material argument too. As in function (geometry, material) , which gets passed to the createScene method too. Ill elaborate in an hour when I goto work. But also, consider using the OBJMTLLoader.js, which I found by accident. And it worked. Flawlessly. Even mapping textures too. I didn't look like an idiot at my work innovation day :)

Comment: // loader
                var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(),
                    callbackModel   = function( geometry, materials ) { createScene( geometry, materials, 90, FLOOR, -50, 105 ) };
                loader.load(  'oakley/building.js', callbackModel  );



 function createScene( geometry, materials, x, y, z, b ) {

                    zmesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials) );
                    zmesh.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
                    zmesh.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                    scene.add( zmesh );
            }'

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. You saved me from pulling my teeth and hair out today. All the tutorials I followed were outdated!